# How to merge list of zoo objects

Tags: r, zoo

I have a list of zoo objects, and I'd like to merge them. I've already made sure that they're all the same length. It seems that in order to merge them, I need to do something like,

```
merge(my_list[[1]],my_list[[2]]...)
```

But this quickly becomes cumbersome as list length increases. Does someone have a suggestion on handling this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
do.call("merge", my_list)
```

Note that the zoo objects do not have to be the same length.