# Convert a multi-series zoo object to a list of single series zoo objects

Tags: r, zoo

Suppose I have the following multi-series zoo object:

```
X.Z <- structure(c(0, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("FTSE100", "FTALLSH")), index = structure(c(5844, 
                                                    5845, 5846), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

I want to convert `X.Z` into a list of `zoo` objects called `FTSE100` and `FTALLSH`. I used the following:

```
X.Zs <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
    X.Zs[[i]] <- X.Z[,i]
}
names(X.Zs) <- colnames(X.Z)
```

Is there any 'more' efficient way than the above?

My question is the reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160424/how-to-merge-list-of-zoo-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply` can do it very simply

`X.Zs <- lapply(X.Z,"[")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819804/how-to-convert-a-matrix-to-a-list-of-column-vectors-in-r):

```
X.Zs <- lapply(seq_len(dim(X.Z)[2L]), function(i) {x <- X.Z[, i]; class(x) <- 'zoo'; x})
names(X.Zs) <- dimnames(X.Z)[[2L]]
```